# Python: Unable to convert integer to string JSON's value

Tags: python, json, pad

In python, trying to convert the key-value pair from integer to string.

Input:

```
data = [
    {'code': 123456, 'value': 32},
    {'code': 987654, 'value': 12}
]
```

Expected Output

```
data = [
    {'code': '123456', 'value': 32},
    {'code': '987654', 'value': 12}
]
```

Trying for code-value.

Comment: what do you mean by *"pad the key-value pair"* ? Only difference I see is that you type-casted the values of `'code'` from `int` to `str`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, You are right @Anonymous

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in data:
    row['code'] = str(row['code'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *dictionary comprehension* inside a *list comprehension* to achieve this:

```
data = [
    {'code': 123456, 'value': 32},
    {'code': 987654, 'value': 12}
]

new_data = [{k: str(v) if k == 'code' else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in data]
```

where `new_data` will hold the data in your desired format as:

```
[{'code': '123456', 'value': 32}, {'code': '987654', 'value': 12}]
```

Inside the *dictionary comprehension* I am checking whether the *key* is `'code'`, and type-casting the value to `str` in case of a match.